# Azure mobile apps not seeing any tables in easy table

Tags: azure

I'm creating a mobile app backend with Azure App Service. I created a database connection to an existing sqlserver db. However, when I clicked on the Easy Tables blade there were no results of the current table. How can I use the existing tables with this mobile app? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK i figured this one out .. make sure the app connection string is correct, then go ahead and add the table to the easy tables list (like a new table), it will pick up all the existing columns in the table automatically!

Be careful: It also messes with the table structure adding deleted and roversion etc columns in azure style. It doesnt seem to delete anything though